# Alternate empty column among dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this `df`:

```
df = data.frame(aa = letters[1:5],
                bb = letters[1:5],
                cc = letters[1:5],
                dd = letters[1:5])
df2 = c('ee', 'ff', 'gg')
df[df2] = NA
```

And I want to have this output:

```
ee  aa  bb  ff  cc  dd  gg
NA  a   a   NA  a   a   NA
NA  b   b   NA  b   b   NA
NA  c   c   NA  c   c   NA
NA  d   d   NA  d   d   NA
NA  e   e   NA  e   e   NA
```

Is there an elegant way to do so instead of:

`df = df[,c('ee', 'aa', 'bb', 'ff', 'cc', 'dd', 'gg')]` ??

Comment: Is this example supposed to be generalized on bigger dfs? Because I don't see an inherent logic in your alternating pattern, which makes it difficult to generalize.

Comment: Is it always blocks of 2 columns?

Comment: @akrun yes, always blocks of 2 columns.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option.  Based on the input/output, we need to have alternate columns within each block of 2 columns,  Created a matrix 'm1' of column names, `split` them by `col` of the matrix, concatenate each `list` element with one of the element of 'df2' to create a vector of column names in the specified order ('un1').  Using that, a 'data.frame' of NA is created (through the `matrix` route) and assign the values of columns of 'df' to that

```
m1 <- matrix(names(df), 2, 2)
un1 <- c(unlist(Map(c, df2[seq_len(nrow(m1))], 
       split(m1, col(m1)))), df2[length(df2)])
dfN <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol =length(un1), 
           nrow = nrow(df), dimnames = list(NULL, un1)))
dfN[names(df)] <- df
dfN
#  ee aa bb ff cc dd gg
#1 NA  a  a NA  a  a NA
#2 NA  b  b NA  b  b NA
#3 NA  c  c NA  c  c NA
#4 NA  d  d NA  d  d NA
#5 NA  e  e NA  e  e NA
```

---

Or another option is `add_column` from `tibble`.  We `split` the dataset into a `list` of `data.frame` based on the 'k' (blocks of column - 2), loop through the `list` and the sequence of `list` with `map2`, add the columns at the beginning (`add_column`), convert it to a single data.frame (`map2_dfc`) and then add the remaining column at the end

```
library(tidyverse)
k <- 2
l1 <- split.default(df, as.integer(gl(ncol(df), k, ncol(df))))
i1 <- seq_along(l1)
nm1 <- tail(names(df), 1)
l1 %>% 
    map2_dfc(., i1, ~ 
                 .x %>% 
                  add_column(!! df2[.y] := NA, .before = 1)) %>% 
                  add_column(!!df2[-i1] := NA, .after = nm1)
#  ee aa bb ff cc dd gg
#1 NA  a  a NA  a  a NA
#2 NA  b  b NA  b  b NA
#3 NA  c  c NA  c  c NA
#4 NA  d  d NA  d  d NA
#5 NA  e  e NA  e  e NA
```

Answer (score 2):

If the names of empty columns do not matter much then you can also use `for` loop. It will result in the desired dataframe named `df2`

```
df = data.frame(aa = letters[1:5],
                bb = letters[1:5],
                cc = letters[1:5],
                dd = letters[1:5])
df2 = NA

for (i in 1:(ncol(df) / 2)) {
  df2 <- data.frame(df2, df[, (i*2-1):(i*2)], NA)
}
```

Column names can be added later if needed as

```
colnames(df2)[seq(1,ncol(df2),3)] <- c('ee', 'ff', 'gg')
```